# How to generate an OpenCV .SO file?

Tags: java, windows, opencv, cmake, terminal

I am new to compiling sources, forgive me if there is already a similar answer here.

I downloaded the OpenCV files from this link https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.5.1.zip

I unzipped the zip, created a folder called build and inside it I applied the following command:

```
cmake -DWITH_QT=ON -DWITH_OPENGL=ON -DFORCE_VTK=ON -DWITH_TBB=ON -DWITH_GDAL=ON -DWITH_XINE=ON -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=C:\Users\LVTLWF631\Desktop\opencv-4.5.1\build
```

and the following log was presented:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/LVTLWF631/Desktop/opencv-4.5.1/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

This is another way I tried

[image]

And this is the log

```
CMake Error: The source "C:/Users/LVTLWF631/Desktop/opencv-4.5.1/modules/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/Users/LVTLWF631/Desktop/opencv-4.5.1/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.
```

I am trying to generate the .so file to work in linux environment. I need this file because I'm going to apply this command in java. I generated any name just to illustrate:

```
System.load("opencv_451.so");
```

How can I compile the opencv source to generate the .so file using windows? Could anyone help?

Comment: please follow the guide on docs.opencv.org. tldr: you gave the wrong paths. the sources path isn't `opencv-4.5.1/modules` but just `opencv-4.5.1` **AND THEN** you should clearly state that you are attempting a "cross compile" (build on windows, for linux). that is harder to get right than a regular build.

Comment: Am i missing something or why does a CMake related question have a java tag? I understand OCV has Java functions but from the question i do not think the java aspect has an impact

Comment: @RAVN Mateus Yes, when I run with the java option it gives an error I don't know why

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Okay, I'll try it on linux somehow